# Time Series Analysis: Use differencing vs. estimating seasonal patterns with sinusoidal components to remove seasonality

Tags: time-series, seasonality

My goal is to remove seasonality of a time series such that I find the underlying stationary process.
As far as I can understand, one can remove seasonality in a time series by either differencing w.r.t. the period/frequency or estimate sinusoidal components, cos/sin, to the data and remove them by such.

From testing I have experienced that differencing removes a lot of observable points proportional to the length of the period, where as by estimating sinusoidal components it keeps all the points.

What are the pros and cons of both strategies and is there anything fundamentally wrong about seeing both strategies as equally good? Are the scenarios that fits

Thank you.

Comment: Seasonal differencing is only appropriate for a narrow class of time series, namely, those that are seasonally integrated. When applied outside this class, seasonal differencing introduces a unit root in the seasonal moving average component, and this is something that should be avoided. *Overdifferencing* is a relevant keyword.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thank you for sharing your wisdom.